# How can you hide a segmented controller?

Tags: ios4, xcode4, hidden, uisegmentedcontrol

I have tried hiding a segmented controller just like a button or label can be hidden in XCode. It's intended to be hidden/shown when touching a parent segmented controller above. This Code would work with Buttons or Labels:

```
mySegmContr.hidden = YES;
```

But it just won't work for segmented controllers. Can you help me out?

Comment: I don't believe it's any different. Please check that mySegmContr is not nil because this should work.

Comment: How do i check if it's nil? Is it nil by default? Because I didn't declare it to be nil in any line of my code. Thanks for your help, you see I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a property for the segment controller you can do more stuff with it like changing it's location, resizing it and want you want hiding it.

In your .h file do this

```
UISegmentedControl *mySegment;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *mySegment;

-(void) createMySegment;
```

In your .m file do this

```
@synthesize mySegment;


- (void) createMySegment     {  
if ([self mySegment] == nil) {      
    NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segName = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] buttons];  
    [self setMySegment:segName];
    [segName release]; 
    segName.frame = CGRectMake(110, 62, 120, 25);           
    segName.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    segName.momentary = NO;
    segName.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [segName addTarget:self
                action:@selector(pickMethod:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:segName];             
} 

}
```

NOTE: With "setMySegment" above make sure you use a capital first letter which is M in "mySegment".
Then when you want to hide it use this. Don't for get to dealloc mySegment.

```
[[self mySegment] setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that you can use a simple UIView in which you put the things you want to hide. The UIView can then be hidden with

```
myView.hidden = YES;
```

still I found no way to hide a segmented control directly.